# Performance suggestions for trees and the GC

Tags: data-structures, go, tree, garbage-collection, abstract-syntax-tree

In my attempt to create a CSS3 parser (https://github.com/tdewolff/css) for my minification library, I'm in the process of optimizing the tokenizer, parser and minifier. The tokenizer is pretty fast but I believe the parser could be optimized.

The parser processes the tokens and generates a tree of nodes representing the syntax. All nodes satisfy this interface:

```
type Node interface {
    Type() NodeType
    String() string
}
```

Example nodes (see https://github.com/tdewolff/css/blob/master/node.go):

```
// root
type NodeStylesheet struct {
    NodeType
    Nodes []Node
}

// example node
type NodeRuleset struct {
    NodeType
    SelGroups []*NodeSelectorGroup
    Decls     []*NodeDeclaration
}

// leave (the only end-leave possible)
type NodeToken struct {
    NodeType
    TokenType
    Data string
}
```

Parsing stylesheet (see https://github.com/tdewolff/css/blob/master/parse.go):

```
func (p *parser) parseStylesheet() *NodeStylesheet {
    n := NewStylesheet()
    for {
        p.skipWhitespace()
        if p.at(ErrorToken) {
            return n
        }
        if p.at(CDOToken) || p.at(CDCToken) {
            n.Nodes = append(n.Nodes, p.shift())
        } else if cn := p.parseAtRule(); cn != nil {
            n.Nodes = append(n.Nodes, cn)
        } else if cn := p.parseRuleset(); cn != nil {
            n.Nodes = append(n.Nodes, cn)
        } else if cn := p.parseDeclaration(); cn != nil {
            n.Nodes = append(n.Nodes, cn)
        } else if !p.at(ErrorToken) {
            n.Nodes = append(n.Nodes, p.shift())
        }
    }
}
```

Each node is allocated on the heap and a significant time is spent on the GC and related tasks. Could I reduce that?

Can I put all element in a flat array for instance? Because the elements of the tree are filled sequentially (ie. it can be flattened). What techniques can I use to reduce (small) allocations on the heap?

### Update

The minifier is actually not really slow, bootstrap (134kB) is minified in 28ms (NodeJS implementations take atleast 45ms and produce larger files http://goalsmashers.github.io/css-minification-benchmark/). But it would be great if I could squeeze out even more!

I know that some time is spent on `[]byte` -> `string` casting, but the `[]byte` from the tokenizer needs to be copied anyways because its memory can be reused at any `tokenizer.Next()` call. Since it needs to be copied anyways, I figured casting to string was better because it made much of the code easier (checking for equality).

I can make a tokenizer variant that keeps the whole file in memory, which is fine for the parser because the parser doesn't stream anyways.

### Update 2

I did load the whole file into memory for the parser and replaced all `string` to '[]byte`, now it's 10% faster! Bootstrap.css now takes 23ms.

I don't think it's worth the hassle to flatten the tree, and it removes some of the flexibility (user able to modify the tree).

Comment: Interesting. Low-hanging: I think it's at least worth looking at object slices instead of pointer slices, which would remove another layer of pointers for the GC to trace through, though that impacts a lot of code. You could test on one type, maybe NodeToken, and see if it helps, and only then try it more broadly.

Comment: In terms of hairier stuff stuff, yes, storing indices into slices could help--you're essentially managing your own memory then. If the memory management isn't too complicated (you don't want to free and reuse nodes, say), that could work. If stuff is immutable or almost so I can see it working, if not, beware.

Comment: Oh, interesting combination: maybe you could allocate largish flat slices of each type ("chunks"), and nodes' `[]NodeSelectorGroup`s etc. are *subslices of those chunks*. One constraint that imposes is that, say, a single ruleset's `SelectorGroup`s all share a "chunk", which probably involves wasting a little RAM when you need 10 selector groups but the current chunk only has room for 5. But it avoids some small allocations and layers of pointers without forcing you to store indices all over the place.

Comment: But don't feel guilty if it's taking 1s to minify Bootstrap or something. You could move forward with code that's easy to work with, and think about high-level optimizations instead, like parallelizing some hard parts or figuring out how to only re-minify the differences when a file changes slightly from the previous version. Or maybe how it is "feels inefficient" but is fine. Or you have RAM to spare and can set GOGC=500. Goal is to make the users happy, whether we make the GC happy or not.

Comment: Ack, finally: memprofile. Sounds like you know that GC is taking a while, and AST operations are a plausible candidate for it, but might as well rule out something wacky like string processing being the real hidden culprit.

Comment: Thanks twotwotwo, I did some memory profiling and removed the []byte -> string conversions and saved 10%. After all I don't think it's worth the hassle to flatten the tree, but it was a nice brain exercise ;)

Comment: Nice. w00t that you were already doing Bootstrap in .028s! :)